# Listen to background process's exit code in MakeFile

Tags: shell, makefile, background-process, spawn

**Solved**
I need to spawn background processes in MakeFile and also consider their exit codes.
  Scenario:

- several processes are spawned in background.
- MakeFile continue evaluation (and do not want to check spawned processes PIDs in some loop an so forth)
- Some process exits with non zero exit code
- make utility exits with non zero exit code

Naturally, I am consider to use `command &` to spawn a process in background.

**Problem:** If command is specified like `command &` then make process **does not** track it's exit code.

**Sample 1**

```
do:
        @false & \
        echo "all is normal"


%make -f exit_status_test.mk
all is normal
```

**Sample 2**

```
do:
        @false && \
        echo "all is normal"


%make -f exit_status_test.mk
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/home/scher/tmp/lock_testing.
```

Sample 1 shows that make utility does not consider exit code of the background process.

P.S. Please do not advice to store spawned processes PIDs and to check them in a loop with some `sleep` delay and so forth. A need to continue evaluation of MakeFile and exit with non zero code automatically.

**Solution**

```
do:
        @(echo "background command" ; (echo "[HANDLER] Prev command exits with $$?")) & \
        echo "doing something"
```

So we can create a sequence of commands to handle exit status of background process.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an ill-conceived attempt to create a `Makefile` that can run multiple jobs in parallel, when in fact make can generally do this for you.

All you need to do is give each job a separate command in make:

```
target: job1 job2

job1:
    some_command

job2:
    some_other_command
```

If you use something like this in your `Makefile` and then run `make -j2 target`, then both `some_command` and `some_other_command` will be run in parallel.

See if you can find a way to get make to run your work in parallel like this.

Comment: I assume is not appropriate for MakeFile I am working with since it is bsd.port.mk from The FreeBSD Ports Collection. All manuals state to be as accurate as possible with -j options, and to write you make file compatible with this option.